# Converting rowwise back to matrix

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I am looking for an operation that creates a matrix from a colwise operation in Eigen.

I could not find an appropriate operation in [VectorwiseOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html) (sorry if I overlooked one).

It seems that it is supported for some operations. First output compiles fine, second output gives an error. (https://www.godbolt.org/z/qrrfa1brx)

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Eigen::Matrix3d m;

    m << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0;

    std::cout << m + m.rowwise().sum().replicate(1, 3) << std::endl; // OK
    std::cout << m + m.rowwise() << std::endl;  // Failure: operator + not found.
}
```

In the context I want to apply this, it is not possible for me to use `rowwise` as an lhs operator. I want to apply other matrix operations on the result.

Maybe an `matri()` or `array()` method in the `VectorwiseOp` would solve this gap.

Comment: Can you describe what you *actually* want to do? Your first expression works, because `.rowwise().sum()` returns a vector, which gets transformed to a matrix by `.replicate()`.

Comment: `rowwise` just acts as a modifier for the operation that you want to do, e.g. in the first case, doing a rowwise sum. Your second statement makes no sense. Did you want to write `m + m.transpose()`? Also, note that `<<` is an arithmetic operator. You often have to put the Eigen expressions in parentheses when using them with `cout` to get the proper order of operations